# How to transform a co-ordinate value in 45 deg-135 deg co-ordinate system to earth co-ordinate system?

Tags: math, matlab, image-processing, geometry, trigonometry

I get a series of square binary images as in the picture below,
[image]

I want to find the red point, which is the point of intersection of four blocks (2 black and 2 white). For doing so, I use to get the sum of all pixel values along the diagonal directions of the square image, which is 45 deg and 135 deg respectively. The intersection of maximum pixel sum 45 deg line and minimum pixel sum 135 deg line is where my red point is.

Now that I get the co-ordinate of the red point in 45 deg-135 deg co-ordinate system, how to I transform them to earth co-ordinates?

In other words, say I have a point in 45deg-135deg co-ordinate system; How do I find the corresponding co-ordinate values in x-y co-ordinate system? What is the transformation matrix?

some more information that might help:

1) if the image is a 60x60 image, I get 120 values in 45deg-135deg system, since i scan each row followed by column to add the pixels.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about matlab, but in general all you need to do is rotate your grid by 45 degrees.
Here's a helpful link; shows you the rotation matrix you need

[wikipedia rotation matrix article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Rotations_in_two_dimensions)

The new coordinates for a point after 2D rotation look like this:
    x' = x \cos \theta - y \sin \theta.
    y' = x \sin \theta + y \cos \theta.

replace theta with 45 (or maybe -45) and you should be all set.

If your red dot starts out at (x,y), then after the -45 degree rotation it will have the new coordinates (x',y'), which are defined as follows:

x' = x cos(-45) - y sin (-45)
y' = x sin (-45) + y cos (-45)

Comment: True, but it's not that simple, because your new image coordinates probably point "between" sampling points of the image, so you have to do some kind of interpolation (for example bilinear). I would rather use the imrotate function to handle that for me (if you have image processing toolbox).

Comment: @WebMonster, it is that simple. Just assume you would do the rotation in the other direction. Then you have the position *where the pixel comes from* and you can interpolate it in the original image. An interpolation 2d is not that hard to implement.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry when I misunderstood your question but why do you rotate the image? The x-value of your red point is just the point where the derivative in x-direction has the maximum absolute value. And for the y-direction it is the same with the derivative in y-direction.

Assume you have the following image

[image]

If you take the first row of the image it has at the beginning all 1 and the for most of the width zeroes. The plot of the first column looks like this.

[image]

Now you convolve this line with the kernel {-1,1} which is only one nested loop over your line and you get

[image]

Going now through this result and extracting the position of the point with the highest value gets you 72. Therefore the x-position of the red point is 73 (since the kernel of the convolution finds the derivative one point too soon).

Therefore, if *data* is the image matrix of the above binary image then extracting your red point position is near to one line in Mathematica

```
Last[Transpose[Position[ListConvolve[{-1, 1}, #] & /@ 
{data[[1]],Transpose[data][[1]]}, 1 | -1]]] + 1
```

Here you get `{73, 86}` which is the correct position if y=0 is the top row. This method should be implemented in a few minutes in any language.

**Remarks:**

1. The approximated derivative which is the result of the convolution can either be negative or positive. This depends whether it is a change from 0 to 1 or vice versa. If you want to search for the highest value, you have to take the absolute value of the convolution result.
2. Remember that the first row in the image matrix is not always in top position of the displayed image. This depends on the software you are using. If you get wrong y values be aware of that.

Comment: The lines are not always 90 deg and 0 deg to earth axis, they keep changing. Think of it as a spinning body. Will this method still work?

Comment: If your square image can be rotated, then I don't understand why you scan 45 and 135 degree. Assume the above square image is rotated exactly 45 degree, then it would be the same situation as if you would just scan lines and columns in the image above. Can you update your post with 3 different square images without any frame or added lines?